# Why must I pass type to make function when variable is already declared?

Tags: go

I want use anonymous struct to do something.

```golang
var users []struct{
    Name string `json:"name,omitempty"`
    Age int
}
```

and I have to write the type again to set value

```golang
users = make([]struct{
    Name string `json:"name,omitempty"`
    Age int
}, 0, 10)
```

if I insist using anonymous struct, is there any way to make it more decent?

(if no, I wonder why golang design make function like this...)

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous structs are handy for one-time use.

If you are using it more than once, then define a named struct type.

If you only use it within a single function, you can define the type within the scope of that particular function, so it's obvious that it cannot be used elsewhere:

```
func myfunc() {
    type MyType struct {
        Name string
    }
    m := MyType{Name: "Hello, World!"} // this type can only be used within this func
    fmt.Println(m)
}
```

Comment: Do note, that types defined within functions *cannot* have methods defined on these types.

Comment: thank you, the solution is nice in some circumstances. But I really like to use anonymous struct. in my opinion, to pass the type again to make() is not necessary, but golang require you to do so, it's weird.

Comment: if i insist to use the anonymous struct, maybe I have to use reflect to make without writing the type again. But I still wonder why make() is like this.

Answer (score 0):

> if I insist using anonymous struct, is there any way to make it more decent?

Yes, there is. Use `:=`:

```
users := make([]struct{
    Name string `json:"name,omitempty"`
    Age int
}, 0, 10)
```

Of course, this only works if you're calling `make` right after you're defining the variable. If these bits are separated by other code, this trick won't work for you.

But don't be afraid to name your types. That's generally a better approach anyway (with or without `:=`).